Visual Studio doesn't auto-complete html tags (angular)
Im trying to do something in angular with html css, components and other thigs. The problem is Visual Studio (no code) doesnt autocomplete tags in html, for example in visual studio CODE you type "div" and press tab and the editor itself complete with " " and place the cursor in the middle.
Any solution? (I cant find anything in internet probably bc anybody use visual studio with angular).
I've tryied everything in the Visual Studio settings, probably missing something

You might want to try and install the extension : "Angular Language Service". You can find the installation in Visual Studio in Extensions->Manage extensions and by typing
"Angular Language Service" in the search bar. Or you can find the installation on the marketplace here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template&ssr=false#overview

If you are having problems with the IntelliSense autocomplete feature in Visual Studio for HTML files. Visual Studio should offer HTML tag autocompletion, but sometimes it's not as complete as Visual Studio Code. I would recommend that you make sure you have the appropriate extensions for Angular installed. Extensions like Angular Language Service can enhance IntelliSense for Angular projects.
There is also a chance that the configurations will become corrupted. You can reset your settings through Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings.
